# ClassNotFoundException when starting chat based activity

Tags: java, android

Re-posting this as I had the wrong title with my previous post and it did not end up anywhere.

Having trouble with this chat window project, it just crashes when the ChatWindow activity is called.

**In the debugger when I click the farm I see this message in the window:**

```
@FastNative
static native Class<?> classForName(String className, boolean shouldInitialize,
        ClassLoader classLoader) throws ClassNotFoundException;
```

**I also see the following message in the Variables window:**

```
Exception = {ClassNotFoundException@3804}
```

**Here is the ChatWindow code(the activity that keeps crashing):**

```
public class ChatWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myDisplay;
    EditText myChat;
    Button mySend;
    ArrayList<String> myList;
    ChatAdapter messageAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_window);



        //declarations
        myDisplay = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        myChat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat);
        mySend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sndBtn);
        myList = new ArrayList<>();
        //in this case, “this” is the ChatWindow, which is-A Context object
        messageAdapter =new ChatAdapter( this );
        myDisplay.setAdapter (messageAdapter);


        //send button actions
        mySend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message;
                message = myChat.getText().toString();
                myList.add(message);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //this restarts the process of getCount()/getView()
                myChat.setText("");

            }
        });

    }
    private class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            public ChatAdapter(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx, 0);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return myList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = ChatWindow.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View result = null ;
            if(position%2 == 0)
                result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_incoming, null);
            else
                result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_outgoing, null);

            TextView message = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            message.setText(   getItem(position)  ); // get the string at position
            return result;


        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Probably the class not found lacks a public constructor

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Its probably something with  class names or consutructor names for classes you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select **app** from **Edit Configurations** and run your code, i solved the same problem this way.
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdlHC.png)

Comment: I tried that way, no change.  I even tried commenting out most of the code including the inner class and I still get the same message.  Could it be the intent code that is wrong? below is the onClick code I am using in the previous activity that launches ChatWindow and results in the error in question:
Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ChatWindow.class);
                startActivity(intent);